# Padarn Session for many users

Tags: padarn

I'm evaluating [Padarn](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Padarn.aspx) for my project and I'm trying to implement a very simple authentication scheme:

```
namespace SampleSite
{
    public class Login : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Form["login"] == "admin" && Request.Form["password"] == "123")
            {
                Session["username"] = "admin";
                Response.Redirect("PostFiles.html");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's working fine for a single user, however, when my friend tried to hit the page while I was debugging, a NullReferenceException was thrown at

```
Session["username"] = "admin";
```

Then we realized it's not working for concurrent users.

Are concurrent sessions really not supported? Is this some configuration I'm missing?

Comment: Concurrent sessions should be fine - the default I think it to allow up to 20.  Two questions: what platform are you running on (i.e. desktop, CE, Mono) and exactly what Padarn build number?

Comment: build is "Evaluation Binaries (v 1.5.13272 : September 2013)", from my ocfhttpd.exe.config file, MaxConnections is indeed set to 20

Comment: Platform is Windows CE 2013

Comment: Correction: Platform is Windows CE 7.0 with Compact Framework 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, for no good reason at all, the hands-on lab ships with a domain set for the cookies.  Even worse, the domain is nonsensical.  It's probably a remnant of some sort of testing we were doing internally and never reverted for release.

What's happening is that the configuration has this in it:

```
<Cookies Domain="169.0.0.2" />
```

This is causing the session cookies to get stripped from any client (unless it's IP happens to be 169.0.0.2).

This, in turn, causes a new session to be generated with every browser request, which effectively throws out your session variables.

Change your web.config to not have a cookie domain like this, and all will be well:

```
<Cookies />
```

The `NullReferenceException` you get in your `Page` code is because the `Session` object on the page in `null`.  This happens when the maximum number of Sessions for the service has been reached (which occurs quickly when each request is generating a new Session).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple sessions are definitely supported.  By default 10 concurrent sessions are supported.

I put together this quick validation test Page:

```
class SessionTest : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newVariable = Request.Form["value"];

        if (newVariable != null)
        {
            Session["TestVariable"] = newVariable;
        }
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        var sessionVariable = Session["TestVariable"];

        writer
            .Html()
                .Body()
                    .Form(t => t
                        [HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, "Test"]
                        ["method", "POST"])

                        .Text(string.Format("CurrentValue: {0}", sessionVariable ?? "[null]"))
                        .Br()
                        .Input(t => t
                                [HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text"]
                                [HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, "value"]
                                [HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Maxlength, "32"])
                        .EndTag() // input
                        .Br()
                        .SubmitButton("Submit", "Submit")
                    .EndTag() // form
                    .Form(t => t
                        [HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, "Reload"]
                        ["method", "POST"])
                        .SubmitButton("Reload", "Reload")
                    .EndTag() // form
                .EndTag() // body
            .EndTag(); // html                
    }
}
```

It simply displays a variable for the current Session and lets you change it.  I opened two browsers, on in IE and one in Chrome, which generates two sessions just like two PCs would.  I then hit the page from both browsers and they showed different saved session state as expected:

[image: From Chrome]
[image: From IE]

Comment: I'm still able to reproduce the issue on the test page but it seems intermitent, I'm trying to find a reproductable error case

Comment: Actually, it's not really working, even when I don't get an exception the value is lost if I reload the page

Comment: I'd need a repro project.  The above code works for me.  I never see an exception and the value remains when I refresh.

Comment: I've sent my project on the support's e-mail